# Add a custom button | CK Editor Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I am trying to add custom button in CKEditor. I am using this CKEditor [ng2-ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor).
It is working fine. but I want to add a button. on clicking this button will add a rails template tag

Example:

I can add the button like example below, but I don't know how to write its method. that will insert `<%= sender_name %>` tag on the current position of text in CKEditor.

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent">
    <ckbutton [name]="'saveButton'"
      [command]="'saveCmd'"
      (click)="save($event)"
      [icon]="'save.png'"
      [label]="'Save Document'"
      [toolbar]="'clipboard,1'">
    </ckbutton>
</ckeditor>
```

please help me. how can I do that in angular2 typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. and it is quite easy. very easy.

in **ckeditor.component.html**

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent">
    <ckbutton [name]="'saveButton'"
      [command]="'insert_name'"
      (click)="insert_name($event)"
      [icon]="'./path/to/icon.png'"
      [label]="'Insert User Name'"
      [toolbar]="'clipboard,1'">
    </ckbutton>
</ckeditor>
```

**ckeditor.component.ts**

```
insert_name(event){
  event.insertText("#{user_name}");
}
```